# Lua Set in Redis is not working as expected

Tags: redis, lua, spring-data-redis

I am new to Lua scripting and facing issues while creating Set in Lua. I am trying to store unique elements in Lua Set using below code but it isn't working as expected.

```
local function test() 
 local t1 = {11,11,22,33,33,44,55,66,77,88,99}
 local t = {}
 for i, v in ipairs(t1)
 do
  t[v] = v
 end
 return t
end
```

This function is supposed to return unique elements from `t1` but it's returning empty array. I think I am doing something wrong but can't figure out what. Can someone help?

Read lot about Lua Sets still couldn't figure out issue. Tried running script locally in docker with different modifications/approaches but nothing helped

Comment: What is the code you are using to tell you that the return value is empty?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that. Do you mean how am I testing it? Actually I was running it on Redis server. Saved logic from this function to lua file(`test.lua`), loaded it on Redis server using `script load` and executed it using `evalsha` command

Comment: The code given is correct; `test` does not return an empty table when called. We can't reproduce your issue because it's somewhere else.

Comment: The code given is not really correct because it uses ```t[v] = v``` for index key defining and has only be corrected to: ```t[i] = v```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis converts Lua table to array reply, and you MUST ensure that your Lua table is an array, i.e. index (table key) starting with 1.

However, in your case, `t[1]` is nil, and Redis takes it as an empty array.

In order to fix the problem, you need to convert `t` to an array:

```
-- Your original code generating table `t`

-- Then convert `t` to an array.
local res = {}
for k, v in pairs(t) do
   res[#res + 1] = v
end
return res
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for your quick reply. This worked. I couldn't find this information in Lua documentation. Probably worth writing small article about it ;) Anyways, thanks again.